# Analyze disk usage on a retina mac

Tags: disk-space, macbook-pro-retina

Disk Inventory X doesn't work on retina screens.  Even if I set it to Scaled -> More Space, the window spawns too small to use and if I resize it I get the "rect width is not an integral value" error and it gets all screwed up.

Is there any other tool out there that can help me figure out what is using up space on my hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround from [macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-can-i-use-instead-of-disk-inventory-on-rmbp.1831985/): right-click the app, click Get Info, and check the box to *run in low resolution mode.*

YMMV, but it did the trick for me !

The [original thread at macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-can-i-use-instead-of-disk-inventory-on-rmbp.1831985/) also lists a few alternatives to Disk Inventory X: [OmniDiskSweeper,](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) and [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a few but Disk Inventory X seems to be the best free one unfortunately.

**Recommend you try:** Omni disk sweeper.

**DaisyDisk** Seems to be the best PAID, offers a download (trial??) but it is a paid app ~$10

link: http://www.daisydiskapp.com/

Good Luck!

p.s. Change Mac Resolution?

Source:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-free-applications-to-analyze-inspect-your-hard-disk-space-mac/
- http://lifehacker.com/5915508/the-best-disk-space-analyzer-for-os-x

Comment: Omni disk sweeper doesn't support mavericks, which is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work again by switching to use the full native resolution on my retina display.  Unfortunately Apple doesn't let you do this out of the box, so you have to install a third party tool.

I used Retina DisplayMenu, found on this site here:
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-hack-to-run-native-resolution.html

Once running at an unscaled resolution, Disk Inventory X behaves correctly.